# is there any possible way to get ussd response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm building an applicatin in flutter and i have a question.
Is there any possible way to get **ussd response** in flutter then use that response to go further in the application like approve if the transaction was successfully like that; without using **ussd_service** which is a silent. i want a pop up to let the user enter like a password to continue and get a response if that transactin was succesfull or not .

Comment: As i can understand you want to enter the password after getting the response from the ussd service. If that is the case you can use ussd service to get the response and after getting the response you can show one dialog to the user to enter the password.

Comment: not like that , i want first to run the ussd code then enter the password then get the response telling me if it went well without any issue.

Comment: did you use ussd service?

Comment: I didn't use it. I am just trying to figure it out. Is your password going to be part of ussd request?